# For $x,y \in G$ prove that $xy=yx$ if and only if $y^{-1}xy=x$ if and only if $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

For the moment, I am just trying to understand the question. Is it asking me to prove that all 3 statements are equivalent? (That any one implies all others)? Will I have to prove 6 different directions?

...although, i suppose that if I prove the first statement implies the second, and that the second implies the third...then obviously (by logic and hypothetical syllogism) the first implies the third.

And then I have to prove the reverse...that the third statement implies the second and that the second implies the first?

Comment: Yes, they want all $6$ directions. But keep in mind that you only need to show $3$ if you can show $A\implies B \implies C \implies A$.

Comment: Technically you have to prove 6 but 3 of them might be trivial.  If you prove $A \implies B$ (by work) and $B \implies C$ (by work) then you can say: if follows that $A \implies C$ (no work!).  As lulu points out if you prove $A \implies B$ and $B\implies C$ and $C \implies A$ then you are done as $A \implies B \implies C$.  $B \implies C \implies A$ and $C\implies A \implies B$ and that is all six.  Not as efficient you can do $A \iff B; A\implies C;C\implies B$.  etc.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to obtain the equivalence of three statements, so you technically need to prove six equivalences, two between each pair of statements. However, if you can form a chain like the comment suggested above, then the other three implications will follow automatically.

For example, $B \implies A$ as $B \implies C \implies A$, and similarly $C \implies B $ because $C \implies A \implies B$. However, the order of $A,B,C$ must be in a manner such that these implications that are sufficient, should be easy to prove.

So, in your case, you have to decide your $A,B,C$ carefully. Maybe this time, I'll do it for you:

$A : xy=yx, B : x^{-1}y^{-1}xy = 1, C : y^{-1}xy = x$.

So you will need to prove $A \implies B$, $B \implies C$ and $C \implies A$. These all work in the same manner, so I will just show one of these as a sample, say $C \implies A$: 
$$
y^{-1}xy = x \implies y(y^{-1}xy) = yx \implies (yy^{-1})xy  = yx \implies xy=yx
$$

The other two implications are very similar in nature.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase $A \iff B \iff C$ is a bit sloppy and strange but ultimately acceptable.

I take it to mean:  Prove 1) $A \iff B$ and Prove 2) $B \iff C$.

It would then follow that $A \implies B \implies C \implies A$ so we can conclude without explicitely proving (or even stating) 3) $A \iff C$.

So an alternative way to do this is to note that on all groups:

$a = b \iff ah = bh$ for all $h \in G$.

Proof:  If $a = b$ then $ah = bh$.  If $ah = bh$ for any $h \in G$ then $ahh^{-1} = bhh^{-1}$ so $a = b$.

Thus 1) $xy = yx \iff y^{-1}xy = y^{-1}yx = 1*x = x$.

And 2) $y^{-1}xy = x \iff x^{-1}y^{-1}xy = x^{-1}x = 1$

And that's it.  As far as I am concerned we have done what is asked.